# Cant Get values from other class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

i try to use value from txtbox in Window1 in other Class
by click button in Window1
i tried more than 100 ways but still not wroking!
how can i get values of txtbox in Window1 when i click button and
get run callstock and in callstock first i get value of textbox from Window1
note : code works fine when i set value "example"
but i cant get that value from class Window1

```
class Window1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(550,200,500,500)
        self.setWindowTitle('program')
        self.UI()

    def UI(self):
        self.txtbox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.txtbox.move(150,10)
        self.txtbox.setPlaceholderText("name")
        btnfind = QPushButton("Find",self)
        btnfind.move(175,35)
        btnfind.clicked.connect(self.getValues)
        self.show()
    def sendval(self):
        txt = self.txtbox.text()
        return txt
    def getValues(self):
        self.newB = callstock()

class callstock(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        wi = Window1.sendval(self)
        self.setWindowTitle(wi)
        self.setGeometry(10,10,500,500)
        self.UI()
        self.figview1 = showchart1(name=wi,day=200)
        self.figview1.setGeometry(10,10,500,500)
        self.figview1.move(0,0)
        self.figview1.show()
    def UI(self):
        pass

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window1()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: you should send first class (or `textbox`) to second class as argument - `self.newB = callstock(self)` where `self` means instance of `Window1` - or `self.newB = callstock(self.textbox)` - and later in `callstock()` you have to assign it to variable `def __init__(self, other_class):` or `def __init__(self, other_textbox):` - and later you can use `w1 = other_class.sendval()` or `w1 = other_class..txtbox.text()` or `w1 = other_textbox.text()`. You CAN'T use `Window1` in other class to access first class.

Comment: you could add all `import` in code to make minimal working code which we could simply copy to create solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send instance of first class to second class as argument - in your code it will be `self` which means instance of `Window1`

```
   self.newB = callstock(self)
```

And second class has to get it - ie. as `other_class`

```
class callstock(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, other_class):    # <-- get instance in `other_class`
        super().__init__()
        
        wi = other_class.txtbox.text()  # <-- use it
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Window1(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(550, 200, 500, 500)  # PEP8: space after comma
        self.setWindowTitle('program')
        self.UI()

    def UI(self):
        self.txtbox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.txtbox.move(150, 10)  # PEP8: space after comma
        self.txtbox.setPlaceholderText("name")
        
        btnfind = QPushButton(self, text="Find")  # PEP8: space after comma
        btnfind.move(175, 35)  # PEP8: space after comma
        btnfind.clicked.connect(self.getValues)
        
        self.show()

    def getValues(self):
        self.newB = CallStock(self)  # <-- send instance of `Window1` as argument


class CallStock(QWidget):  # PEP8: `CamelCaseName` for classes
    
    def __init__(self, other_class):    # <-- get instance in variable `other_class`
        super().__init__()
        
        wi = other_class.txtbox.text()  # <-- use it
        
        self.setWindowTitle(wi)
        self.setGeometry(10, 10, 500, 500)  # PEP8: space after comma
        self.UI()

        self.figview1 = QLabel(self, text="Text from Window1: " + wi)
        #self.figview1 = showchart1(name=wi, day=200)  # PEP8: space after comma
        self.figview1.setGeometry(10, 10, 500, 500)  # PEP8: space after comma
        self.figview1.move(0, 0)  # PEP8: space after comma
        self.figview1.show()
        
        self.show()
        
    def UI(self):
        pass

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window1()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

**EDIT:**

You could also send only text instead of full instance

```
    self.newB = CallStock(self.txtbox.text())
```

and

```
class CallStock(QWidget):  # PEP8: `CamelCaseName` for classes
    
    def __init__(self, wi):  # <-- get text in variable `wi`
```

Minimal working code:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Window1(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(550, 200, 500, 500)  # PEP8: space after comma
        self.setWindowTitle('program')
        self.UI()

    def UI(self):
        self.txtbox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.txtbox.move(150, 10)  # PEP8: space after comma
        self.txtbox.setPlaceholderText("name")
        
        btnfind = QPushButton(self, text="Find")  # PEP8: space after comma
        btnfind.move(175, 35)  # PEP8: space after comma
        btnfind.clicked.connect(self.getValues)
        
        self.show()

    def getValues(self):
        self.newB = CallStock(self.txtbox.text())


class CallStock(QWidget):  # PEP8: `CamelCaseName` for classes
    
    def __init__(self, wi):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setWindowTitle(wi)
        self.setGeometry(10, 10, 500, 500)  # PEP8: space after comma
        self.UI()

        self.figview1 = QLabel(self, text="Text from Window1: " + wi)
        #self.figview1 = showchart1(name=wi, day=200)  # PEP8: space after comma
        self.figview1.setGeometry(10, 10, 500, 500)  # PEP8: space after comma
        self.figview1.move(0, 0)  # PEP8: space after comma
        self.figview1.show()
        
        self.show()
        
    def UI(self):
        pass

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window1()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: tanq a lot my problem solved